# Rake mailer task only sends newsletter to last subscriber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, mailer

Last night I found out my rake mailer task that sends my newsletter, only sends it to the last subscriber. But why?! I use Heroku Scheduler to perform the task.

This is my code in `scheduler.rake`:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :send_newsletter => :environment do
  if Time.now.saturday?
    NewsletterMailer.weekly_best.deliver
  end
end
```

This is how I defined `weekly_best` in my `NewsletterMailer`:

```
def weekly_best
  @subscriptions = NewsletterSubscription.where(active: true)

  @plugins = Plugin.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week).where("cached_votes_up > ?", 0).order(:cached_votes_up => :desc).first(5)

  @subscriptions.each do |s|
    mail(to: s.email, from: "Great Wavelengths <hi@greatwavelengths.com>", subject: "Weekly best gear")
  end
end
```

As you can see I do iterate over all the email addresses of the subscriptions, but then why does it not send it to everyone?

Hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `NewsletterMailer.weekly_best` will return only the last email from your `@subscriptions.each` loop. Then you call `deliver` on this one single email, and that is why only one email is sent.

To fix it you need to call `deliver` on each mail separately. You could do something like this:

```
class NewsletterMailer
  def self.deliver_weekly_best
    subscriptions = NewsletterSubscription.where(active: true)
    plugins = Plugin.where(...)

    # Call deliver for each subscription   
    subscriptions.each { |sub| weekly_best(sub, plugins).deliver } 
  end

  def weekly_best(sub, plugins)
    @plugins = plugins
    mail(to: sub.email, ...)
  end
end
```

Then in your schedule you just do:

```
NewsletterMailer.deliver_weekly_best
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, Christmas happened. Yes, that worked, thanks a lot!